# PayPal smart buttons, how to always open the credit card in a new tab?

Tags: paypal

I use PayPal smart buttons for integrating payments into a website, following this [live demo](https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/client)

I have two problems with the "Debit or Credit Card" button:

1. It is not always working, when I click on it, the fields are expanding and shown on the same page (my server) and after entering all the info and click "Pay Now" I get message saying "Something went wrong, we will take you back to checkout so you can try again" when I click on "Try again" button a new tab opens for processing the credit card payment on PayPal server (now it will work). 
   this happens ~50% of the time.
2. It is related to the first one, the first view (when fields expanding on my site page) it lacks the address fields however they are shown after clicking "Try again" and go to the PayPal tab.

So my question is, can I unify the way that the credit card payment view is shown? Is there a parameter that I can pass while rendering the buttons that makes it always open in a new tab?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. The message "Something went wrong, we will take you back to checkout so you can try again" will happen when there is a decline. As you are apparently testing payments yourself, you can expect many such intentional declines by PayPal. They aren't considered a technical or integration problem, but the system behaving as designed.
2. There is no way to make the black Debit or Credit Card button open a new window. You can disable it if you don't want it, but you can't make it behave differently.

When there is an error or decline using that Debit or Credit Card path, and you click "Try again", it is the same as using the top PayPal button. That is the fallback path.